# Kotlin: Comparing two different lists with different sizes to find a shared value and change elements when it occurs

Tags: kotlin

Given list A containing the following data:

```
arrayListOf(Product(uid = "1", name = "Product 1", isOnListB = false), Product(uid = "2", name = "Product 2", isOnListB = false), Product(uid = "3", name = "Product 3", isOnListB = false))
```

And list B containing the following:

```
arrayListOf(FavoriteProduct(uid = "2", dateAdded = "Today"))
```

What is Kotlin's idiomatic way to see if a product on list A is on list B and then make a change to that product?

In the example above, you can see that both lists contain a different data type and the only data they share that can be the same is the `uid` attribute.

Whenever the same `uid` value is on both lists, then the respective element from list A should be updated to say it's on list B (`isOnListB`).

Comment: Are these large lists?

Comment: Would the lists not be better stored as maps, perhaps keyed on the `uid`?  Then you can look up a product by UID directly (and efficiently).

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha We can assume that list A (products) is larger than list B (favorite products).

Answer (score 0):

Setup:

```
data class Product(val uid: String, val name: String, var isOnListB: Boolean)
data class FavoriteProduct(val uid: String, val dateAdded: String)
val prods = arrayListOf(Product(uid = "1", name = "Product 1", isOnListB = false), Product(uid = "2", name = "Product 2", isOnListB = false), Product(uid = "3", name = "Product 3", isOnListB = false))
val favs = arrayListOf(FavoriteProduct(uid = "2", dateAdded = "Today"))
```

Simple `O(|favs| |prods|)` solution:

```
prods.forEach { prod ->
    if (favs.any { fav -> prod.uid == fav.uid })
        prod.isOnListB = true
}
```

Although as others mentioned it's probably more efficient to store the products as HashMap, and even just update the one as it is added by the user.

Comment: Your solution works, but as you wrote, it could be done more efficiently.